# Can I share a 3G connection from an iPhone/iPad by creating a Wi-fi hotspot?

Tags: iphone, ipad, internet-sharing, tethering

I've been wondering about this for awhile. So, is it possible to create a Wi-fi hotspot from an iPhone or 3G iPad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's called "Personal Hotspot" by Apple and works on iPhone 4 and 4S. [Here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4517) is an Apple support doc on it.
Not available on the 3G iPad though, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. Longer answer, there are two ways of doing it:

- Legal (using contract from your mobile provider)
- Jailbreaking (using Cydia)

This [Gadget Review article](http://www.gadgetreview.com/2011/09/how-to-turn-your-iphone-into-a-wifi-hotspot.html) covers both methods, using both the built-in iOS Personal Hotspot option and the Cydia MyWi app. Other articles include this [MacWorld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/158556/2011/03/personal_hotspot_att.html) and the [AT&T Wi-Fi main page](http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/wifi.jsp). Wired has a [Verizion-specific article](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/02/verizon-iphone-hotspot/) as well.

For the iPad 2, it looks like it's possible with the MyWi app, according to [this page](http://www.ipadtomactransfer.org/ipad-2/how-to-set-up-hotspot-on-ipad-2.html). Have never tried it myself though.